# Is it possible to batch upload images to Pinterest?

Tags: pinterest

Is it possible to batch upload images to Pinterest and be able to manage all of the descriptions, links etc from one dashboard, instead of having to manually upload each image individually.

Answer (score 1):

The best workflow ive found so far is by using Zapier, you can create a Zap (custom workflow) to take any images in a Dropbox folder and auto pin them to a Pinterest board.

The Zap sets the title of the pin as the title of the image file you place in Dropbox.

From there you can go into Pinterest and set tags, descriptions etc if required.